# Laravel: How change PDF styling in maatwebsite DOMPDF export?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, pdf, export-to-pdf

I am exporting PDF files with every entry.
But they are too simple, i.e: no styling.

Here is a screenshot:[image]

But as you can see, there is no styling other then the styling is used for my Excel export. I want to add a logo image on top. Remove the extra columns and add some header text like Company name, address etc....
Here is my Controller:

```
public function export_release(Request $request)
{
    Excel::store(new \App\Exports\ReleaseExportView($request->reference),'uploads/release/'.$request->reference.'/'.'release_'.$request->reference.'.pdf','real_public', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::DOMPDF);
    return redirect()->route('release_inventory')->with('success','Outbound has been Created.');
}
```

Here is my Export class:

```
use App\outbound_detail;
use App\outbound_temp;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;

class ReleaseExportView implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents
{
    protected $reference;
    function __construct($reference) {
        $this->reference = $reference;
 }

    public function collection()
    {
        //link for StackOverFlow
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57153985/how-to-pass-parameter-to-export-file-of-laravel-excel-for-db-query

        return outbound_detail::where('reference',$this->reference)->get([
            'reference', 'sku_parent', 'sku_child', 'cases'
        ]);
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [

            'Reference',
            'SKU Parent',
            'SKU Child',
            'Cases Released'
        ];
   }
   // ...

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class    => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                $cellRange = 'A1:W1'; // All headers
                $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setSize(14);
            },
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all Remove ShouldAutoSize, to fit the data in your file.
Then edit A1:W1 in AfterSheet. I'm still researching on adding company info also

Answer (score 1):

you can return Blade view instead of array and  customize the layout there

```
 public function view(): View
    {
      $data = [];
      return view('yourBladeView', [
          'details' => $data
      ]);
    }
```